# Is the sentence “Could I smoke here?" ungrammatical?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, conditional-constructions, questions

The correct sentence is "Can I smoke here?", but I wonder why I can't use "could" in this question.

Comment: Actually, the correct sentence is "_May_ I smoke here?"  One presumes the person asking the question is capable of smoking, and is using "can" to mean "is allowed".

Comment: "Sure, if set on fire" came the answer.. +1 To Monty's comment, by the way - " 'can' suggests ability, 'may' suggests permission". If could is the equivalent of can (to you), you might still not be allowed to smoke there even if you had the ability (I.e. you were currently or had recently been on fire)

Answer (score 12):

Actually I think it's more what is *idiomatic* than what is *grammatical*.  There is nothing wrong with, "Could I smoke here?" but it doesn't mean the same thing as, "Can I smoke here?"

"Could", in this context, is often a *conditional*.  It implies you're asking if it's possible to do something, *if some other condition is met*.  For example:

> I know you don't like people smoking in your car, but it's been hours since my last cigarette.  **If I rolled down the window, could** I smoke?

[More on the differences between "could" and "can".](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-could-and-can/)

(Edit) as FumbleFingers points out, the actual conditional requirement can be *unstated*, or even something as basic as "... if I want to".  "Could" merely implies that there is *some* conditional involved.

(Edit2)  Muzer and others point out that *could* is often used as a slightly more deferential way to say *can*, in which case, "Could I smoke?" is perfectly natural.  "*May* I smoke?" may be more common, though.

Comment: I think the [required?] "conditional" could be merely implied, not explicitly stated. Which could in principle (in *practice*, so far as I'm concerned) be something as "weak" as *[**...if I wanted to**]*. Given ***here***, the circumstances must be pretty "immediate", but you could certainly assume ***if we went in this cafe*** if spoken outside the cafe before having definitely agreed to enter.

Comment: ...plus of course there's the greater "distance" implied by using ***could, would*** instead of ***can, will***, reflecting deferential / hesitant politeness. Hence you might ask **Would** I be allowed to smoke?* instead of ***Will** I be allowed?* (itself already a "distanced irrealis" version of ***Am** I allowed?*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  or combinations with "may/might", e.g. *"I wonder if I might possibly be allowed to smoke here?"*

Comment: Yeah - ***I wonder if*** and ***possibly*** are definitely part of any (non-self-respecting :) "deferential groveller's" linguistic armoury / toolkit. Whether it *really* increases one's chances of a favourable reaction is debatable, but I bet you'd be more likely to get a polite rather than dismissive refusal, which would be at least *some* comfort to the haplessly enforced non-smoker.

Comment: btw - strictly speaking I think it's either *If I **roll** down the window, **can** I smoke?* or *If I **rolled** down the window, **could** I smoke?* But I'm not an expert on grammar / pedantry, so I only *think* that - I don't claim to *know* it.

Comment: **Could** is also used in British English as a slightly softer-sounding alternative to **can**, when asking for permission to do something. I don't think anyone ever thinks about a conditional, implied or otherwise, in these cases.

Comment: (American here.) In response to "Can i ...?" questions, it's reasonably common to hear "I don't know, can you?" sorts of responses--when the asker is clearly asking for permission. So, "May i smoke?" feels more correct, at least in American English.

Comment: @Muzer I don't think that's limited to British English. It is quite common in the US as well.

Comment: @Tashus fair enough, you're probably right. In fact it could well have originated from the US, come to think of it I can't figure out if it's the sort of thing I would have grown up with or the sort of thing I picked up later from American television.

Comment: @bw That is a common distinction enforced by pedantic schoolteachers and parents, but there is an appropriate definition for "can" in these cases: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can

Comment: @Tashus as in Q: "Do you know the way to London?" A: "Yes."

Comment: @Muzer That sort of response was drilled into me when I was young, to emphasize that "can" and "may" really do have different meanings, and that using "may" in this case resolves a lot of ambiguity brought about by "can" being seen as an informal variant of "may".

Comment: How unfortunate that it wasn't drilled into some when they were young that sarcastically making fun out of people's usage of what someone _thinks_ is the wrong word but probably isn't instead of actually Answering The Damn Question might not be the most polite thing to do. (I've been through that phase myself and I'm embarrassed to remember it.)

Answer (score 4):

> Could I smoke here?

adds some unknown condition, for example you don't actually have any cigarettes, or a lighter, or it is raining hard, or you don't have time to smoke.

Comment: I think Gill is right [here](https://youtu.be/2ip8kwjiW6w). As she explains, in the use #2, either **can** or **could** might be used, but **could** expresses a polite request whereas **can** is not quite as polite.

Comment: @LucianSava at which time in that 18 minute YouTube does Gill come to the point? I am a native English speaker with a formal education. I might miss some points of grammar but I don't need lessons. Can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: Sorry for my comment, I didn't mean to offend you. She merely presents a simplified explanation.

Comment: @LucianSava a simplified explanation that’s 18 minutes long!?

Comment: Of the point in question @Tim, ie #2 which lasts perhaps 1-2 minutes, in case you didn't notice what are we talking about here.